# circular #defines in C

Tags: c, random, c-preprocessor

Please note -- I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to maintain / improve it.

One of my header files contains these lines:

```
/* macros to seed the random number generator */
/* This is needed on Windows which throws an error due to 'random' 
not being defined on MingW.  I'll clean it up later. */
#define srandom srand
#define random rand

/* New random seed function. */
#define srand srandom
#define rand random

#define rnd(x)  ((int)(rand() % (x)) + 1)
#define rund(x) ((int)(rand() % (x)))
```

Furthermore, I have man pages for all four functions `rand`, `srand`, `random`, `srandom`, so I would assume that these are all valid C functions.

Can you help me understand / figure out what happens when I call `rnd(10)` ?  Is this undefined behavior?  Does one definition "override" the other somehow?

(I'm asking because I feel like I get a lot of low numbers in my actual program, even though my test programs seem to work correctly and distribute randomly.)

---

Just a quick note that I am almost positive that the "lot of low numbers" I was seeing was probably an error in operator precedence and parentheses, causing a long boolean to always evaluate as "true".

Comment: Have you tried running `cpp` to see how the preprocessor actually behaves?

Comment: https://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/LibraryFunc/rand.htm

Comment: Are you sure you haven't cut out some conditional compilation directives that affect which of those macro definitions are effective?  Those are pretty commonly used in conjunction with macros such as you present.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the header file was copied verbatim.  No `#if` directives around the `#define` statments.  That's why I was confused about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C preprocessor will not evaluate the same macro expansion more than once for a given expansion. That is, it will break the cycle as soon as it identifies it. Therefore, in your case the following expansions will happen:

```
rnd(10) // list of available macros: [srandom, random, srand, rand, rnd(x), rund(x)]
```

```c
((int)(rand() % (10)) + 1) // list of available macros: [srandom, random, srand, rand, rund(x)]
```

```
((int)(random() % (10)) + 1) // list of available macros: [srandom, random, srand, rund(x)]
```

```
((int)(rand() % (10)) + 1) // list of available macros: [srandom, srand, rund(x)]
```

On the last step the pre processor will find no more available expansions (the rand one was already done) and will give up.

That has nothing to do with why you're seeing more small numbers than big numbers, though. That could be related with different definitions of `RAND_MAX`. In a very contrieved example, if `RAND_MAX = 10`, then 0 has 18% of chance of showing up while the other numbers have a 9% chance. Not only that, typical rand implementations tend to have low entropy for lower bits. If having a uniform distribution is important to you, you may want to look outside of the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

The effect of recursive preprocessor macros is well-defined: while expanding the definition of a macro `foo`, if the name `foo` is found again, it is left alone. So in your case, `rand` expands to `random` which expands to `rand` which is not expanded further.

Technically, the behavior of these definitions is undefined if your code also includes `stdlib.h`, because the behavior is undefined if you define (or undefine) a macro whose name is also the name of a standard library function which is pulled in by an included header. In practice, if the standard library headers only define those names as functions and not as macros, these macro definitions won't have any effect. If they define the names as macros, you'll get a compilation error.

The functions `rand` and `srand` are defined by the core C language and are available whenever you include `stdlib.h` (except on some embedded implementations that don't provide the full C library). `random` and `srandom` are Unix/POSIX additions, and to use them, you need to define a symbol such as `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` before `#include <stdlib.h>`.

I'm puzzled how these definitions could fix anything on MinGW. If MinGW doesn't define `random` at all, then a call `random()` is expanded by the preprocessor to `random()` and still tries to call a function that isn't defined. This looks like either a series of successive hacks resulted in harmless leftover cruft, or someone fumbled to solve a problem, ended up solving it in a different way, but committed that part even though it didn't contribute to the solution.

Comment: The behavior of the code is undefined even in the unlikely event that `stdlib.h` is *not* included.  Identifiers of standard library functions are reserved even if the header designated for declaring them is not included.  The situation with respect to undefinedness is as you describe only for the identifiers of standard macros.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not that it matters much, but why is that? From C99 TC2 (N1124) §7.1.3: “Each identifier with file scope (…) is reserved for use (…) **if any of its associated headers is included**“. I don't see another clause that would apply if the header is not included. Names of standard library functions are reserved as identifiers with external linkage regardless of header inclusions, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: Look one point up: "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage."

Comment: @JohnBollinger: only as identifiers with external linkage, not as macros or in other contexts.

Comment: "Reserved for use as" == "may not be used for any other purpose".  So I suppose that without including the header, the OP could declare their own *functions* with the same names, but they may not declare macros with those names.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, it's the opposite. You may not define `rand` as a macro if you include `stdlib.h`. You may not define `rand` as a non-static function even if you don't include `stdlib.h`. With typical implementations, that's easily understood: the compiler cares about macros but not about what identifiers the standard library provides; the linker can only have one definition per identifier and doesn't know about included header.

Comment: More likely someone added the first macros to get it working in mingw. Then, later on, someone was displeased with the use of rnd instead of random and made the second change, without testing in mingw (possibly because the guy who used windows is not around anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler has a magical option -E to see the expansions.

https://godbolt.org/z/_PIvet

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return rand(x);
}

int foo(int x)
{
    return rnd(x);
}
```

expands to

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return rand(x);
}

int foo(int x)
{
    return ((int)(rand() % (x)) + 1);
}
```

BTW IMO it is better to use inline functions instead.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the first pre-processor will update source and replace `srand` with `srandom` then it will update the source again and replace `srandom` with `srand`. I have checked with `cpp` and it looks ok. Program works as well. I was having second thoughts on `srand` macro as there is a functions in `stdlib.h` with identical name but nothing bad happened.